# How to determine if there exist at least one number that is generated by both of the given generating functions?

Tags: combinatorics, power-series, generating-functions

I'm just learning about Generating Functions so my question might not completely make sense (in that case, I apologize). I want to know whether there exist at least one number that is generated by both generating functions $f:=\cfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}}$ and $g:=\cfrac{x^k}{(1-x)^{k+1}}$ where $k=3,4,...,n$. If there exist such number(s) (I don't know how to determine that) what are they?

**Update**

1. By "a number that is generated by both generating functions" I meant that a number exists that is the coefficient of both generating functions.
2. There exists solutions (two equal coefficients) if k=3,4,5 ... However how can I show that there exist only 1 solution if k=n? Or there exist multiple solutions? Or there exist no solutions?

Comment: When I read "number generated by a generating function", I would think that this number is a coefficient in the power series of that generating function. Is that what you have in mind? Also, generating functions are defined as power series. Now, there are various flavors of power series, like ordinary and exponential power series. So if you just give the closed forms of the generating functions in your question, it's not clear what kind of power series you're interested in.

Comment: Are you looking for any two equal coefficients, ie maybe $f_j = g_l$ for $j,l$ arbitrary, or should $j=l$?

Comment: @john_leo: I'm looking for two equal coefficients i.e. $f_j=g_l$ for $j,l$ arbitrary.

Comment: Regarding the second point of your update, I have the impression that it's undecidable to know how many solutions there are, but I don't know for sure. But maybe you can find a good reason why some of the coefficients appear in the other sequence. I would consult [OEIS](http://oeis.org/), maybe you can find something interesting there.

Answer (score 0):

The [Taylor series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) of a generating function gives you the coefficients (I guess that's what you mean by "number generated by the generating function) of a generating function. If you're too lazy to work out the expansions by hand, then you can let [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series%281%2F%28sqrt%281-4*z%29%29%29) do the work. After a little of try-and-error you should be able to find coefficients that are in both expansions.

Comment: There exist solutions (two equal coefficients) if k=3,4,5 ... However how can I show that there exist only 1 solution if k=n? Or there exist multiple solutions? Or there exist no solutions?